# How to use Indy component to Send from a IDTCPServer socket with Multiple Bindings

Tags: delphi, indy

I wish to use multiple bindings on a `TIdTCPServer` socket component to send data to multiple different clients. I can successfully create the bindings and assign a different port number to each. Here is my code to create the bindings:

```
IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
{create the new sockets}
for i := 0 to NumberOfItemsSpin.Value-1 do
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add;
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Items[i].Port := StartingPortSpin.Value+i;
end;
SocketsCreatedCount := IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Count;
Timer1.Enabled      := SocketsCreatedCount > 0;
IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
```

The clients know the IP address and port to connect to, and are able to make a successful connection. However, I need to *asynchronously* *send* data to any one of the connected clients based on certain events.

I know I can detect a `OnExecute` event, get the `Context` and reply, but my server socket needs to work asynchronously. It will not be polled by the Client.

I know the client IP Address and port number from the connection info. However, I cannot find a way to send data to a specific client. How do I use the component to correctly map the binding and send data to the correct connected client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a bit of a misunderstanding of how `TIdTCPServer` actually works.

The `Bindings` collection has nothing to do with the individual clients.  The `Binding` items are simply the IP/Port pairs that the server listens on for connections.  There is no mapping between a `Binding` and a client.  When a client connects, a `TIdContext` object is created for it and stored in the server's `Contexts` list, and then the `OnConnect`/`OnDisconnect`/`OnExecute` events are triggered for that `TIdContext`, independently of the other clients.  `TIdTCPserver` is multi-threaded, each client is run in its own dedicated thread, and the events for a given client are triggered within that client's thread, so events for multiple clients can be running in parallel.

The `OnExecute` event is NOT dependent on a client polling the server.  The event is simply called in a continuous loop for the lifetime of the client's connection.  The event handler decides what to do with the client on each loop iteration.  However, you are required to assign a handler, or else an exception will be raised when the server is activated (to avoid that, you can derive a new class from `TIdTCPServer` and override its `CheckOkToBeActive()` method to not raise an exception).

To send data to any particular client, simply locate that client's `TIdContext` object within the server's `Contexts` list, and then you will have access to its associated `TIdTCPConnection` object for exchanging data with that client.

However, performing the send from inside the same loop that searches the `Contexts` list is inheritantly unsafe, so I would suggest instead that you create a per-client thread-safe queue (such as a `TIdThreadSafe(String|Object)List` instance) to hold your outbound data, and then when you locate the client you can put the data into that client's associated queue.  Then you can have the `OnExecute` event handler send the content of its client's queue whenever it is not empty.  This way, you avoid clients blocking each other, error handling is localized to each client, and you can send data to multiple clients in parallel.

To associate a queue with each client, you can either:

- use the public `TIdContext.Data` property.
- derive a new class from `TIdServerContext`, add your own custom fields to it as needed, and then assign that class to the server's `ContextClass` property before activating the server.  You can then type-cast any `TIdContext` object pointer to access your custom fields.

For a code example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14061527/65863) I posted to an earlier question:

[How do I send a command to a single client instead of all of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053329/)